# operator ALL in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a task to select positions all workers of which get salary between 400-700$. But my query does not work I do not know why.

```
SELECT DISTINCT position
FROM 
    job
WHERE position = ALL   
(SELECT
        position
     FROM 
        job
    WHERE 
        salary BETWEEN 400 and 700);
```

Comment: Is this one attempt?  or two?

Comment: one value can not be equal all values from subquery, not?

Comment: Try `IN` or `=ANY` instead of `= ALL`

Comment: `ALL` is a used to apply an operator to each RHS operand in a list and combine the results with `AND`. A single value cannot be equal to every value in a list unless it is a list of duplicates.

Comment: To solve your problem: all workers of each position get salary between minimum and maximum value of that position (it seems an obvious statement). If minimum is greater than or equal to 400, then all the workers get salary more than 400. The same is for maximum with reversed comparison. Put it together and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the condition:

```
select a.* 
  from ( select distinct position from job) a
 where position not in (
         select position
           from job
          where salary < 400 or salary > 700
       )
```

You also might want to read about how ALL operator works like. Your query incorrectly assumes all positions are the same (otherwise ALL will not work).

Alternatively, use ALL twice:

```
select a.* 
  from (
    select distinct position 
       from job
           ) a
where 400 >=  ALL (
              select salary
                 from job
                where position = a.position
           )
  and 700 <=  ALL (
              select salary
                 from job
                where position = a.position
           )
```